# How to write and read class from binary file in c++

Tags: c++, class, binary, fstream

i am learning fstream in c++ and id like to write a class in binary, then retrieve it. and of course , it all went horribly wrong.

heres the class

```
class Student
{
private:
    const char* name;
    int age;
public:
    Student()
    {

    };
    Student(const char* name, int age) : name{ name }, age{ age }{};
    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "name : " << this->name << std::endl << "age : " << this->age << std::endl;
    }
};
```

the writting class (which i think works)

```
void writeDatabase()
{
    Student jack("jack", 21);
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&jack), sizeof(jack));
        std::cout << "wrote to file";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error opening file when writing to database\n";
    }
    file.close();
}
```

where i am stuck

```
void readData()
{
    Student st;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "opened file\n";
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&st), sizeof(st));
        st.display();
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error opening file when reading\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance, and the error is a read access violation :)

Comment: Read up on *serialization* and *de-serialization*. You cannot just write any class raw byte by byte to a file and read it back. Especially not if it contains pointer or reference members or complex classes like `std::list` etc.

Comment: *the writting class (which i think works)* -- No it doesn't.  You are writing a pointer value to a file.  If you opened the file, you will see that the word "jack" is nowhere to be found, but instead junk.

Comment: that sounds terrible, i will admit i do see junk. but then i tought that was just binary magic.

Comment: `age` is ok, since it is POD (plain old data).  Any complex variables, including dynamic variables at the other end of pointers, are not part of the struct so are not saved.

Comment: ok it seems i tried to jump steps too quickly here, i might need to read up on this.

Comment: @Dems314 You need to write the data that your class represents, not the raw bytes of your object.  A "name" means characters, thus you write character data in some way so that you can recreate the object when read in.   If you had an `char **` representing a chess board, do you think that writing a double pointer saves the state of the chess game to a file?  Of course not -- you would need more than that.  That's the gist of what serialization and deserialization are about.

Comment: @stark yeah, i removed name and it worked, il try to figure out the rest my self, thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here isn't that you're reading or writing the bytes from disk incorrectly. Rather, the problem you're running into is that those bytes don't mean what you intend them to mean.

Your class has a data member `name` that's a `const char *`. That's a pointer to some location in memory that contains the name. When you use the `write` function to write the data from your type to disk, it's storing that pointer on disk somewhere. When you then load the data from disk, it's reloading that pointer.

The problem is that *the pointer* isn't what you want to store. If you reload the pointer from disk, it'll point to the same spot in memory that it used to, but there's no reason to suspect that you'll find the student's name sitting in memory at the place it's pointing. If you've closed the program and then reopened it, you shouldn't see any memory from the previous run.

To fix this, you'll need to change how you write the data to disk. Instead of copying the raw bytes from the class, instead see if you can find a way to write out the name and the age in some way that you can then read that data back in. For example, maybe you'd write it to disk as the age, then a space, then the name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: my goodness, that would have never even crossed my mind, i removed the name field completely and kept age, and the reading works. i need some books.

Comment: No worries! C++ is a language with a lot of moving parts, and writing/reading data from a stream takes some practice even if you know what you're doing.